# Static Polymorphism with boost variant single visitor vs multi visitor vs dynamic polymorphism

Tags: c++, performance, templates, boost, polymorphism

I am comparing the performance of the following methods of C++ Polymorphism:

Method [1]. static polymorphism using boost variants with a separate visitor for each method
Method [2]. static polymorphism using boost variants with a single visitor that calls different method using method overloading
Method [3]. Plain old dynamic polymorphism

Platform:
- Intel x86 64 bit Red Hat modern multi-core processor, 32 GB RAM
- gcc (GCC) 4.8.1 with -O2 optimization
- Boost 1.6.0

Some findings:

- Method [1] seems to have significantly outperform Methods [2] and [3]
- Method [3] outperforms Method [2] most of the time

My question is, why does Method [2] where I am using a visitor but using method overloading to call the correct method give worse performance than virtual methods. I would expect static polymorphism to fare better than dynamic polymorphism. I understand there is some cost of the extra parameter that is being passed in method [2] to figure which visit() method of the class to call and possibly some more branching due to method overloading? But shouldn"t this still outperform virtual methods?

Code is below:

```
// qcpptest.hpp

#ifndef INCLUDED_QCPPTEST_H
#define INCLUDED_QCPPTEST_H

#include <boost/variant.hpp>

class IShape {
 public:
  virtual void rotate() = 0;
  virtual void spin() = 0;
};

class Square : public IShape {
 public:
  void rotate() {
   // std::cout << "Square:I am rotating" << std::endl;
    }
  void spin() { 
    // std::cout << "Square:I am spinning" << std::endl; 
  }
};

class Circle : public IShape {
 public:
  void rotate() { 
    // std::cout << "Circle:I am rotating" << std::endl; 
  }
  void spin() {
   // std::cout << "Circle:I am spinning" << std::endl; 
}
};

// template variation

// enum class M {ADD, DEL};
struct ADD {};
struct DEL {};

class TSquare {
    int i;
 public:
    void visit(const ADD& add) {
        this->i++;
    // std::cout << "TSquare:I am rotating" << std::endl;
  }
    void visit(const DEL& del) {
        this->i++;
    // std::cout << "TSquare:I am spinning" << std::endl;
  }

    void spin() {
        this->i++;
     // std::cout << "TSquare:I am rotating" << std::endl; 
 }
    void rotate() {
        this->i++;
     // std::cout << "TSquare:I am spinning" << std::endl; 
 }
};

class TCircle {
    int i;
 public:
    void visit(const ADD& add) {
        this->i++;
    // std::cout << "TCircle:I am rotating" << std::endl;
  }
    void visit(const DEL& del) {
        this->i++;
    // std::cout << "TCircle:I am spinning" << std::endl;
  }
    void spin() { 
        this->i++;
        // std::cout << "TSquare:I am rotating" << std::endl; 
    }
    void rotate() {
    this->i++; 
        // std::cout << "TSquare:I am spinning" << std::endl; 
    }
};

class MultiVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<void> {
 public:
  template <typename T, typename U>

    void operator()(T& t, const U& u) {
    // std::cout << "visit" << std::endl;
    t.visit(u);
  }
};

// separate visitors, single dispatch

class RotateVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<void> {
 public:
  template <class T>
  void operator()(T& x) {
    x.rotate();
  }
};

class SpinVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<void> {
 public:
  template <class T>
  void operator()(T& x) {
    x.spin();
  }
};

#endif

// qcpptest.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "qcpptest.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>

using MV = boost::variant<ADD, DEL>;
// MV const add = M::ADD;
// MV const del = M::DEL;
static MV const add = ADD();
static MV const del = DEL();

void make_virtual_shapes(int iters) {
  // std::cout << "make_virtual_shapes" << std::endl;
  std::vector<IShape*> shapes;
  shapes.push_back(new Square());
  shapes.push_back(new Circle());

  boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start =
      boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
    for (IShape* shape : shapes) {
      shape->rotate();
      shape->spin();
    }
  }

  boost::chrono::nanoseconds nanos =
      boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
  std::cout << "make_virtual_shapes took " << nanos.count() * 1e-6
            << " millis\n";
}

void make_template_shapes(int iters) {
  // std::cout << "make_template_shapes" << std::endl;
  using TShapes = boost::variant<TSquare, TCircle>;
  // using MV = boost::variant< M >;

  // xyz
  std::vector<TShapes> tshapes;
  tshapes.push_back(TSquare());
  tshapes.push_back(TCircle());
  MultiVisitor mv;

  boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start =
      boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
    for (TShapes& shape : tshapes) {
      boost::apply_visitor(mv, shape, add);
      boost::apply_visitor(mv, shape, del);
      // boost::apply_visitor(sv, shape);
    }
  }
  boost::chrono::nanoseconds nanos =
      boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
  std::cout << "make_template_shapes took " << nanos.count() * 1e-6
            << " millis\n";
}

void make_template_shapes_single(int iters) {
  // std::cout << "make_template_shapes_single" << std::endl;
  using TShapes = boost::variant<TSquare, TCircle>;
  // xyz
  std::vector<TShapes> tshapes;
  tshapes.push_back(TSquare());
  tshapes.push_back(TCircle());
  SpinVisitor sv;
  RotateVisitor rv;

  boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start =
      boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
    for (TShapes& shape : tshapes) {
      boost::apply_visitor(rv, shape);
      boost::apply_visitor(sv, shape);
    }
  }
  boost::chrono::nanoseconds nanos =
      boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
  std::cout << "make_template_shapes_single took " << nanos.count() * 1e-6
            << " millis\n";
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  std::cout << "Hello, cmake" << std::endl;

  int iters = atoi(argv[1]);

  make_virtual_shapes(iters);
  make_template_shapes(iters);
  make_template_shapes_single(iters);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This program segfaults for me when compiled with `-O3`. Are you sure your logic is correct?

Comment: Only segfaults if no argv[1] is provided :)

Comment: Yeah you need to provide an argument such as 10 or 1000 or 1000000. That's how many times it'll run the loop.

Answer (score 6):

Method 2 is basically reimplementing dynamic dispatch inefficiently. When you have:

```
shape->rotate();
shape->spin();
```

That's involves looking up the right function in the vtable and calling it. The inefficiency from that lookup. But when you have:

```
boost::apply_visitor(mv, shape, add);
```

That explodes roughly into (assuming an `add<>` member function template which is just a `reinterpret_cast` without checking):

```
if (shape.which() == 0) {
    if (add.which() == 0) {
        mv(shape.as<TSquare&>(), add.as<ADD&>());
    }
    else if (add.which() == 1) {
        mv(shape.as<TSquare&>(), add.as<DEL&>());
    }
    else {
        // ???
    }
}
else if (shape.which() == 1) {
    if (add.which() == 0) {
        mv(shape.as<TCircle&>(), add.as<ADD&>());
    }
    else if (add.which() == 1) {
        mv(shape.as<TCircle&>(), add.as<DEL&>());
    }
    else {
        // ???
    }
}
else {
   // ???
}
```

Here, we have a combinatorial explosion of branches (which we didn't have to do in Method 1) but we actually have to check every possible static type of every variant to figure out what we had to do (which we didn't have to do in Method 3). And those branches won't be able to be predicted since you're taking a different one every time, so you can't pipeline any sort of code without coming to a screeching halt.

The overloading on `mv()` is free - it's the figuring out what we're calling `mv` with that isn't. Note also the delta time that would happen based on changing either of the two axes:

```
+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------+
|               |    Method 1    |    Method 2    | Method 3 |
+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------+
|    New Type   | More Expensive | More Expensive |   Free   |
| New Operation |      Free      | More Expensive |   Free*  |
+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------+
```

Method 1 becomes more expensive on adding new types because we have to explicitly iterate over all of our types. Adding new operations is free since it doesn't matter what the operation is.

Method 3 is free to add new types and freeish to add new operations - the only change is increase in vtable. That will have some effects due to object size but will generally be smaller than the increased iteration over types.

Comment: Thanks. Question:
1. Wouldn't there be a check in apply_visitor() for method 1 as well, although it would be a single level to check which shape the visitor is being called with? Which means Method 2 has "1 additional check":
So Method 1:
if (shape.which() == 0) {
...
}
else if(shape.which() == 1) {
...
}

Method 2:
  - as you depicted, so 2 checks instead of 1.

so one additional "if" condition is that expensive?

Comment: My point is, with greater than two types I can understand that there could be multiple compares, but in my example there are only 2 types hence Method 2 should only result in "1" more comparison than Method 2. The impact on the performance seems to be disproportionately large.

Comment: @Sid Not two types, two *variants*. You don't have one more comparison, you have one more nested comparison. It's not just like adding one more type into the method 1 variant.

Comment: I understand that it's a nested comparison but in my example even the nested comparison will result in only one extra CMP operation right? Since the second variant (and hence the second nested loop) has only 2 types.

Comment: @Sid There are jumps involved too. Code unpredictability is bad.

Comment: Hmm ok. So in your opinion if the scenario consists of at the most 4-5 types does going with Method 1 make more sense or Method 3. Method 1, although more performant, leads to an unwieldy design of having "n" separate visitor classes - "n" being the number of methods (in my case there are about 20).

Comment: @Sid I never said any of those things. I am simply explaining why Method 2 is slow.

Comment: I understand but I'm asking if you have an opinion 

Comment: @Sid Depends entirely on the details of the types and their intended usage. It's a very broad question.

Comment: As an update, thanks for your answer and it's helpful and points towards what would be at least one factor leading to the performance issues - but I am not yet convinced that the extra if and branch prediction are the only factors causing the difference - I wonder if looking at the object code would help.

Comment: I don't think this is actually a problem. The whole if/else thing can be flattened to the same complexity as a vtable lookup. I suspect the penalty is in the code-cache/data-cache difference.